# Unable to start windows

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot

I got the blue screen of death about a month ago on my windows machine. Startup repair failed to fix the issue so I reinstalled windows. Forunatly I had a dual boot system with linux which worked perfectly fine so I was able to save all of my files. After I reinstalled windows everything worked fine for a few days then every time I restarted my computer I got the blue screen of death and had to launch start up repair to fix it. It always worked after just a few seconds and I could use my computer normally. Today however I turned my computer on and got the blue screen of death again, I launched start up repair and after 2 hours it said it can't automatically fix the start up. I can run my PC fine in safe mode but cant do anything else. What could be causing this issue and how do I fix it. My ownly idea is that there could be a bad sector in my hard drive.

Comment: If you suspect bad sectors then have you tested the drive?

Comment: If one uses the same NTSF-formatted  disk for Linux and Windows, occasionally I've found that Linux makes changes to the disk that Windows does not "understand". Since your machine is working well in Linux, that might be the case. In particular, I've noticed that the *hiberfil* can be damaged, so I no longer use Hibernate in Windows.